# NSTimer doesn't work in background？

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have developed an application in which I'm running a countdown timer. The timer fires a method every second. However, when the phone is in sleep mode, the timer becomes slow or even turns off.And when I press the home button, the timer turns off.
If someone understand what exactly we need, please tell me.Thanks!

Comment: Background task mumble mumble mumble...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to register your app for some background execution.
I am too having the same issue, but I guess mine could be solved as I will register for Location background support, and I have noticed in another SO question that NSTimer works when you have registered you app for some background execution. Here it is [NSTimer on background IS working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187741/nstimer-on-background-is-working)

For background execution please read apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4

Comment: Hello,Sohail!I read apple documentation for background execution but I still not understander it! How to register mine app for some background execution,for example how to write code ?Can you help me?Thanks.