# NSTimer selector is not called in global queque

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, gcdasyncsocket

I try to create a socket as shown below:

```
socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0))
```

and I implement the func:

```
func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16){
    pingTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "sendPing:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func sendPing(){
    print("will send ping...")
}
```

But the `sendPing` will never be called, and if I try this:

```
socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
```

the `deletegateQueue` is `socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())`, it will work fine.

The UI updating is use main queue, so I want to do socket connection with another type queue, `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)` seems to be a good one.

How can I make it work well?

Comment: The selector for the timer should be `"sendPing"` (without the colon) so it matched the actual function you wrote.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't  think it is caused by the colon, because if i use 'dispatch_get_main_queue' , it works fine. And of course i try remove the colon, still not work.

Comment: You should review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569693/timer-inside-global-queue-is-not-calling-in-ios

Comment: a strong +1 for rmaddy's comment.