# NSTimer lag fire after background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, nstimer

```
timer = [NSTimer bk_timerWithTimeInterval:60 block:^(NSTimer *timer) { ....} repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


+ (id)bk_timerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)inTimeInterval block:(void (^)(NSTimer *timer))block repeats:(BOOL)inRepeats
{
    NSParameterAssert(block != nil);
    return [self timerWithTimeInterval:inTimeInterval target:self selector:@selector(bk_executeBlockFromTimer:) userInfo:[block copy] repeats:inRepeats];
}

+ (void)bk_executeBlockFromTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    void (^block)(NSTimer *) = [aTimer userInfo];
    if (block) block(aTimer);
}
```

If I fold and unfold application after a few minutes, almost always the timer is firing immediately and sometimes it fire with delay. 
Why the timer does not always work immediately?

Comment: You mean you don't stop the timer when the app goes to the background?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheduled NSTimer when app is in background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415870/scheduled-nstimer-when-app-is-in-background)

Comment: Yes, i don't stop timer when the app goes to the background.

Comment: Same problem here for all versions of iOS.

Answer (score -1):

try to add this in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" in your Appdelegate

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier locationUpdater =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:locationUpdater];

        locationUpdater=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    } ];
```

Comment: Needless to say, this only gives you a finite amount of time (a few minutes) before your app is truly suspended.

Comment: I dont' want execute timer in the background. I want the timer fire immediately after the app go to the foreground.