# How to come Ios App to foreground from background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background-process

I working on swift for Ios App. I want to phone user connect specific wifi. So i open iphone wifi settings by NSURL like [this](https://gist.github.com/phynet/471089a51b8f940f0fb4). After then my app go to background and i control ssid every 500ms in background by background task like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27895060). When phone connect the specific wifi i can see this status and i stop background task. But i cant comes my app to foreground. I tried open my app use NSURL metod like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9gtL0Y4DaE) (i add custom url my info.plist and add application function in my appdelagate) but my app has no return use this metod.

Comment: It is not possible to bring you app to the foreground in iOS. You will need to alert the user with a `UILocalNotification`.

Comment: A background app can't force itself to foreground. Fortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately bringing an app from background to foreground is not possible. You can however send a notification or a badge for the user to click and open the app. The user should have notifications enabled for this to work.

Happy Coding!