# fetching data from app while app is in background Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, background, locationmanager

I'm trying to figure out a way to have my app's user notified when he/she travels a mile, my code is as following:

```
var roundDistance:Double!
var startTime = NSTimeInterval()
var timeCounter = NSTimer()
var counter = 0
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = locations.first
    } else {
        if let lastLocation = locations.last {
            let distance = startLocation.distanceFromLocation(lastLocation)
            let lastDistance = lastLocation.distanceFromLocation(lastLocation)
            let startPoint = startLocation.coordinate
            let lastPoint = lastLocation.coordinate
            let blah = locations.last!.coordinate
            var area = [blah,lastPoint]
            var polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &area, count: area.count)
            mapOfMaps.addOverlay(polyLine)

            traveledDistance += lastDistance
            SpeedLevel.text = "\(lastLocation.speed) mph"
            roundDistance = round(100*(distance/1609.344))/100 //converting my distance to miles
            distanceLabel.text = "\(roundDistance!) miles"
        }
    }
    lastLocation = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)) //zoom in on user's location on map
    self.mapOfMaps.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
 func updateCounter(){
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    print("STRAIGHT DISTANCE: \(roundDistance!)")
    if (roundDistance == 1.0){
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "you've ran \(String(roundDistance!)) miles!"
        //notification.alertAction = "open" 
        notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:1)
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
 @IBAction func StartItUp(sender: UIButton) { //start timer and starts location services 
    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    timeCounter = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(CardioViewController.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

now for my explanation on my coding: I added a timer (`counter`) because I also want to time my app's user. I've noticed that `func updateCounter()` is still being run when my app is in the background so I figured if I set my code to check if `roundDistance` has reached a mile in the function, my app would send a notification. No luck! I've come to conclusion that perhaps my app isn't updating the user's location while it is in the background, which is why my timer is being updated in the background but `roundDistance` isn't. Can someone please help me with a solution where I can have the location and `roundDistance` updated real time while my app is in the background?

Comment: NSTimer won't run in the background; it wil when you are debugging with Xcode but not "in the real world".

Comment: @Paulw11 are you serious? :( is there any way I can have a timer run in the background?

Comment: Yes, I am serious,  You take a timestamp when the app enters the bwckground and compare it with the current time when the app returns to the foreground; that is your elapsed time.  But if you implement location background mode properly you should be getting regular location updates which you can also use to check elapsed time by comparing timestamps.

Comment: @Paulw11 I appreciate you telling me that the timer doesn't run in the background. I found this link that has helped me run the timer in the background (in case anybody needs similar help) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894834/swift-how-to-use-nstimer-background

Comment: That will work for up to 3 minutes of background execution time and then your app will be killed.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ugh, i know. But I cant find any other solution. the solution you gave me might be the best one but it seems a little too complicated for my level of programming right now.