# Take an action in background in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm making an alarm with `UILocalNotification`, if first time alarm action is not taken, it snooze again after 5 mins, if not action taken then it snooze again after 5 mins and then I need to send some data in web server, how to implement this?

I can't handle app or take any action when it is not in foreground, is there any other way parallel of broadcasting receiver in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach of always scheduling the connection to the webserver in 10 min with a NSTimer and then discarding it on interaction of any of your local notifications. You could e.g. keep a flag in the app delegate.
See [BackgroundExecution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

You have only 10 min of non-externally triggered background execution - which would be enough for you. There are some workarounds, which you can find here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415870/scheduled-nstimer-when-app-is-in-background?lq=1)

Schedule local notifications as described here [UILocalNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/) in 5 and 10 min. Handle the opening via local notification in your app delegate and discard

Comment: i need to check in background is  UILocalNotification arrived, if notification is not shown, then i need to trigger another notification after 5 min, so i need to  always check if any local notification arrived in background and then send data to web server from background. I can handle all these if i see the notification from didReceiveLocalNotification method, when  i dont see how to do all these? can you provide me code please? @MarkHim