# WebService Call after timeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I want to my Webservice invoke once every 6 Hours.I am newer in iOS. Please help any help would be apperciated.I am stuck.

Comment: Use NSTimer to invoke a method periodically.

Comment: You can use Background refresh mode, but there is no way to schedule for a particular interval such as 6 hours.  If you need exactly six hours then a silent push from your server is the only way

Answer (score 3):

You can user NSTimer and schedule it for 6 hours

```
        NSTimer *timer = nil;
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6*60*60 //6 hour
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(performAction)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks but when user kill application this method invoke or not. I want invoke in any situation.

Comment: You may have a look at this for running in background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415870/scheduled-nstimer-when-app-is-in-background

Answer (score 0):

you can call using NSTimer. this is automatically called which time you set.
e.g.

```
  NSTimer *timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0(your time) target:self selector:@selector(someMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)someMethod
{
   ////API called here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when user kill application this method invoke or not. I want invoke in any situation.

Comment: if application is kill then no method is called. if application background state then it is called. there is no possibility to called methods if application is killed.

Comment: but you call methods in AppDelegate file.- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: You can request a background task that will give you about 3 minutes but you cannot schedule an NSTimer for 10 hours and expect it to fire while your app is in the background, whether your app is killed or not

Answer (score 0):

```
In ViewDidLoad 
 NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:360.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideandview) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    -(void)hideandview
    {
       ////API called here...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the last time in prefence (NSUserDefaults) when you make a call.

Whenever the app starts. Start timer and check  current time with last saved time and get the difference.