# iOS 10 - App is not working in background mode after 3 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, ios10, background-mode

I am connecting an external bluetooth peripheral to iPhone 5S(iOS 10.0.1).
Peripheral sends data at every 2 seconds.

After 4 minutes(approx), peripheral goes idle & app will not receiving data from peripheral.

When I put app in background when peripheral goes idle, then upto 3 minutes (approx) app can upload/fetch data.

But I want to upload data after 25 minutes, & app is not working with 'NSTimer' or 'performSelector:afterdelay' after 3 minutes.

Can anyone have better suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you enable "uses Bluetooth peripherals" background mode then your app will receive notifications from the peripheral in the background, but there is no way to initiate a transmission from your app in the background after a specified period of time. iOS background execution doesn't work like that.

Comment: What is the 'specified period of time'?
Have Apple provided such docs?

Comment: I mean that there is no way to initiate sending of data after **any** period of time when your app in the background. Time-based "wake up" is not supported for iOS apps.  With CoreBluetooth background mode your app can respond to peripheral discovery, peripheral connection/disconnection and a notification from the peripheral.  Refer to the Core Bluetooth programming guide from Apple

Comment: Thank you for reply, Paulw.
I have also noticed by logging in background mode using 'NSTimer'. The app will be alive in background upto 3 minutes.
I also observe, "External peripheral connection keeps application alive for a long time until it sends data", is that correct?

Comment: your solution is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313020/count-while-in-background-nstimer-for-more-than-3-mins/35314268#35314268

Comment: @mylittleswift the solution will work only when you are using location services for a purpose in your app otherwise Apple stands to reject your app.