# NSTimer update interval changes when app goes to background in iOS app?

Tags: ios, nstimer, nsrunloop

I was recording a sample of `CMDeviceMotion` acceleration data for 30 seconds through `NSTimer`. The thing is, when the app is in foreground, everything is fine. The interval is set to `0.01` and in `30 seconds`, `3000` readings are stored. But when app goes to background, I get `300` only readings.

```
self.deviceMotionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(recordUpdates) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Is this how NSTimer works?

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` will never work in background. When your app goes to background, NSTimer also freezes. In short, You can't use NSTimer, when you want to do some repetitive task in background.

If you still want to run something in background, then use the answer given by @Robert in this thread:
[Scheduled NSTimer when app is in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415870/scheduled-nstimer-when-app-is-in-background)