# User inactivity is not working when Screen off or phone lock state in my ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c

User inactivity is not working when Screen off or phone lock state in my ios app
I'm using this code in my project

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994884/8569442

Answer (score 0):

Usually NSTimer is not suited to work in background.

You have to write workaround to put it in background task like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17445799/6777970) or use app delegate methods to do something you need after application is back in foreground like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8415995/6777970).

Comment: what about Screen off issue